# SNMP v1 trap send not working with snmp4j

Tags: java, connection, snmp, snmp-trap

I'm trying to send a trap v1 using snmp4j. It doesn't throwns any exception and execute everything, but the trap is not reaching its destiny. Am I missing something? Is there another way to do it? The IP and the ports in the code are corrects. What would be wrong?

Here's the code:

```
public class SNMPv1 {


  public static final String  community  = "public";

  public static final String  trapOid          = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.2595.1.2";                         

  public static final String  ipAddress      = "10.200.1.220";

  public static final String  agentIPAddress      = "10.200.1.120";

  public static final int     port      = 164;

  private static final int    specificTrap = 1; 


 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     SNMPv1 snmp4JTrap = new SNMPv1();

      /* Sending V1 Trap */ 


      snmp4JTrap.sendSnmpV1Trap();

  }


  public void sendSnmpV1Trap()
  {
      try
          {
   //Create Transport Mapping
  TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
  transport.listen();

  //Create Target 
  CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
  comtarget.setCommunity(new OctetString(community));
  comtarget.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version1);
  comtarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress(ipAddress + "/" + port));
  comtarget.setRetries(4);
  comtarget.setTimeout(10000);

  //Create PDU for V1
  PDUv1 pdu = new PDUv1();
  pdu.setType(PDU.V1TRAP);
  pdu.setEnterprise(new OID(trapOid));
  pdu.setGenericTrap(PDUv1.ENTERPRISE_SPECIFIC); // 6
  pdu.setSpecificTrap(specificTrap);
  pdu.setAgentAddress(new IpAddress(agentIPAddress));

  VariableBinding v = new VariableBinding();
  v.setOid(SnmpConstants.sysName);
  v.setVariable(new OctetString("Param1"));
  pdu.add(v);

  VariableBinding v2 = new VariableBinding();
  v2.setOid(SnmpConstants.sysName);
  v2.setVariable(new OctetString("Param2"));
  pdu.add(v2);

  VariableBinding v3 = new VariableBinding();
  v3.setOid(SnmpConstants.sysName);
  v3.setVariable(new OctetString("Param3"));
  pdu.add(v3);

  VariableBinding v4 = new VariableBinding();
  v4.setOid(SnmpConstants.sysName);
  v4.setVariable(new OctetString("Param4"));
  pdu.add(v4);

  VariableBinding v5 = new VariableBinding();
  v5.setOid(SnmpConstants.sysName);
  v5.setVariable(new OctetString("Param5"));
  pdu.add(v5);

  VariableBinding v6 = new VariableBinding();
  v6.setOid(SnmpConstants.sysName);
  v6.setVariable(new OctetString("Param6"));
  pdu.add(v6);


  //Send the PDU
  Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);
  System.out.println("Sending trap to" + ipAddress + ":" + port);
  snmp.send(pdu, comtarget);
  snmp.close();
  System.out.println("Trap send successfully!!");
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
   System.err.println("Error sending Trap to " + ipAddress + ":" + port);
   System.err.println("Exception Message = " + e.getMessage());
 }
}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that port is correct ? SNMP traps are normally 162, IIRC ?

Comment: I know that traps usually are 162, but they are listening to 164 for some reason that i don't know. but is 164

Comment: Try to utilize Wireshark to see if the packet has left the source machine. That's the quickest way to see if the wire loses the packet.